# Additional bars while displaying pie chart inside iframe in HTML

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, tornado

I have some data using which I've created various graphs and is displayed in a web browser. I use packages like tornado, mathplotlib and pandas to achieve this in python 2.7. The problem is, whenever I display a pie chart in the web page, I have 2 additional blocks behind the pie chart. I don't know from where it comes.

I have a list of scenarios from which user gets to select a scenario. For each scenario, a separate kind of graph is displayed. Only when a pie chart is displayed, I have this problem of having the additional bars behind the pie chart.As you can see from the image, the user can select any scenario and an appropriate graph will be displayed. In all scenarios where a pie chart is to be displayed I have 2 blue bars behind the pie chart. The blue bars are from a previous scenario I guess.

[image: Screenshot]

**This is my python code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import logging
import io
#create logger
logger = logging.getLogger("Overall")

#create console handler
logging.basicConfig(filename='logfiles/Overall.log',level=logging.DEBUG,
    FORMAT='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(message)s')



def overall_level():
'''
This module is used to overall Level (HL,IL,LL)
'''
try:
    with open('FormattedSample.csv') as fopen:
        high,inter,low,rem = 0,0,0,0;
        head_list = fopen.readline()
        heading = head_list.split(",")
        ind = heading.index("mathscl")
        for data in fopen:
            line=data.split(',')

            #checking the math scale score to find the count 
            if(float(line[ind]) >= 275):
                high += 1
            elif(float(line[ind]) >= 230 and float(line[ind]) < 275):
                inter += 1
            elif(float(line[ind]) >= 226 and float(line[ind]) < 230):
                low += 1
            else:
                rem += 1
except IOError as e:
    print e.strerror
    #'application' code
    logger.error(e.strerror)
except:
    print "Sorry for the inconvience\nWe Will Rectificy soon"

    #Exception will be stored in overall
    logger.exception("Unexpected Error:")

else:
    print "HIgher End",high
    print "Intermediate End",inter
    print "Low End",low
    print "Remaining",rem

    # Graphs in the pie chart

    x = pd.Series([high,inter,low,rem],name="")
    plt.title("Overall Count Percentage of Levels")
    x.plot(kind='pie', labels=['High Level', 'Intermediate', 'Low Level', 'Remaining'], colors=['r', 'g', 'b', 'c'],
          autopct='%.2f', fontsize=20, figsize=(7, 7))

    memdata = io.BytesIO()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig(memdata, format='png')
    image = memdata.getvalue()
    return image
```

I cannot find a way to remove this additional bars. This is my HTML code. In fact i only added the necessary html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head><title>Main Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script          
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <scrip 
     src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">   
    </script>
    <style>

     .test + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
      background-color: #3A2734;
      color: #857E00;
      border: 1px ;
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 20px;
      width: 1500%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr><td> <img src="logos.jpg" width="100%" height="50%" /> </td> <td>

    <div><center>
    <h3> Data Analytics & Visualization on Students Achievement in Mathematics          
    on National Achievement Survey
    </h3>
     </center></div> </td></tr>
     </table>
     <iframe width="100%" height="500px"        
       src="http://localhost:8870/comparisionstates" name="iframe"></iframe>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Select Scenarios</a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost:8870/comparisionstates"    
      target="iframe">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="test" href="http://localhost:8870/statewisepass" data- 
       toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" target="iframe" title="OverAll   
      State Pass and Fail Percentage">1</a></li>
        <li><a class="test" href="http://localhost:8870/indiState" data- 
         toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" target="iframe" title="Individual   
        State Wise Pass and Fail Percentage">2</a></li>
        <li><a class="test" href="http://localhost:8870/comparisionstates" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" target="iframe" title="Comparision State wise Pass and Fail Percentage">3</a></li>
        <li><a class="test" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" target="iframe" title="State and Gender Wise Pass and Fail Percentage">4</a></li>
        <li><a class="test" href="#" target="iframe" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Area and Gender Wise Pass and Fail Percentage">5</a></li>
        <li><a class="test" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" target="iframe" title="Top Scorer">6</a></li>
        <li><a class="test" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" target="iframe" title="Gender wise High Level,Intermediate Level,Low Level percentage">7</a></li>
        <li><a class="test" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" target="iframe" title="Medium Wise Pass and Fail Percentage">8</a></li>
        <li><a class="test" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" target="iframe" title="Area Medium Wise">9</a></li>
        <li><a class="test" href="http://localhost:8870/overalllevel" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" target="iframe" title="Overall Count of High Level,Intermediate Level,Low Level">10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
          </div>
    </nav>


    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are re-using the same axes/figure multiple times.  The simplest solution is to call `plt.clf()`.  The better solution is to use the OO interface.

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked. I added `plt.clf()` at the beginning of graph and it worked.

Comment: you should answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rightly pointed out by [tcaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380231/tcaswell), I was re-using the same axes/figure multiple times. That's the reason for such an image. I added `plt.clf()` in the first line of graph generation and the problem was solved.

Here is what i did

```
plt.clf()
x = pd.Series([high,inter,low,rem],name="")
plt.title("Overall Count Percentage of Levels")
x.plot(kind='pie', labels=['High Level', 'Intermediate', 'Low Level'
'Remaining'], colors=['r', 'g', 'b', 'c'],
      autopct='%.2f', fontsize=20, figsize=(7, 7))

memdata = io.BytesIO()
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig(memdata, format='png')
image = memdata.getvalue()
return image
```